# how to use jquery selector with multiple conditions including :hidden and :lt

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use jquery selector to find elements that are both hidden and contain a specific attribute. To make it even more complex, I want to limit this to the first 3 Here is what I have tried:

```
 $found = $(".item[data-findable='true']:hidden:lt(3)");
```

While this produces no error, it also produces no results and stops javascript dead

using just :hidden or :lt and even both together is fine, like so:

```
found = $(".item:hidden:lt(3)");
```

If I call the "data-findable" attribute I get the correct result, so it does exist.

Finally just to cover all bases I tried using true as a boolean instead of a string. i.e:

```
$found = $(".item[data-findable=true]:hidden:lt(3)");
```

Comment: Does that work? If not, how does it not work?

Comment: Thank you for responding. No, it fails silently but also stops javascript. I have added more information to my question.

Comment: Are you sure their markup looks like this `<tag class="item" data-findable="true" style="dsplay:none;" />`?

Comment: @Finglish: are you able to create a (minimal/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can try and work out what's going wrong?

Comment: Mocked up a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8Pg2q/ -- Everything seems to be working.

Comment: $("div[data-findable='true']:hidden:lt(3)").length will have correct result

Comment: You can try `$(".item:hidden:lt(3)").find('[data-findable=true')` instead. But `$(".item[data-findable='true']:hidden:lt(3)")` works well in my Chrome.

Comment: as Manisnish Jangir says, this works ok in Chrome.  For some reason In firefox it wasn't, after updating firefox the problem was resolved, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".item[data-findable=true]:hidden").slice(0,3);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mCSw2/1/

Comment: I marked this correct as it does work as it worked well in my case, but also check out the comments under the question